# raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar uma ferramenta que abre um URL junto com `/robots.txt` e retornar o que tá escrito nele, código:

```
site = input("Digite o dominio:")
api = f'{site}/robots.txt'
pagina = urllib.request.urlopen(api)

print(pagina.read())
```

Porém está apresentando esse erro:

```
raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)

ValueError: unknown url type: 'uol.com.br/robots.txt'
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou perfeitamente: https://repl.it/@acwoss/VerifiableUncommonIde. Como você executou o código? Qual foi a entrada que colocou?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss vc notou que agora pode mudar os nomes dos 'repls' no repl.it? Os nomes que ele gera são terriveis. Sempre quando ia procurar algo ficava perdido, agora vc pode até criar pastas. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Eu sei o que você está fazendo de errado, **os sites não são compostos apenas pelo nome + ".com.br"**(depende), os sites são compostos dessa forma(Também depende):

**protocolo + "www." + nome + dominio**, é mais ou menos assim:

**https://     www.    google .com.br**, caso você não faça assim , você vai obter justamente esse erro. Eu adaptei o seu código e coloquei tratamento de erros, agora deve funcionar certinho e se você digitar o link errado, não vai dar erro.

Execute esse código em **Python 3**, e lembre-se, alguns sites não são **https**, eles podem ser **http** por exemplo. Outros sites não tem o **.com.br**, eles podem ter **.me**, **.gov**,etc...

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
acessar_dados = "sim"

# Entrada
site = input("Digite o dominio, tipo https://www.google.com: ")

# Junção da entrada com a string
api = site+"/robots.txt"

# Tratamentos de erros caso o link seja inválido
try:
 pagina = urllib.request.urlopen(api)
except:
 print("O link '{}' é inválido!".format(site))
 acessar_dados="não"

# Se não aconteceram erros, vamos ler a página!
if acessar_dados=="sim":
 print(pagina.read())
```